# Why is this search input not clickable? Using react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, react-native

***Hello everybody!***

I am developing a weather application on React Native. In my project I have installed [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete)

I took the code of a basic example from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) and inserted it into my application:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

export const GooglePlacesInput = () => {
    return (
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Search'
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                console.log(data, details);
            }}
            query={{
                key: 'my key here...',
                language: 'en',
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SACuq.png)

Hurray, everything works. But for some reason, the search bar is not clickable. I click on it, but nothing happens, I cannot write there.

**Please tell me what could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need this:

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.setAddressText('Some Text');
}, []);
```

and then in your view:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    ref={ref}
    ...
/>
```